# Nmap reports an open port as closed

Tags: nmap

I'm running an OpenVPN server and can use it normally; I know for a fact that the port is open. Running an Nmap scan on port 1194 (the one I'm using) says it is closed. What could be causing this incorrect response? Used this command:

`nmap -p 1194 <ip.address>`

Which yields:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1194/tcp closed openvpn
```

Comment: what parameters are you using for nmap?

Comment: OpenVPN runs on UDP/1194 by default, not on TCP. Are you sure it’s listing on TCP/1194 (what does `lsof` tell you?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out. Since VPNs use UDP, you need to tell nmap to scan UDP ports using the `-sU` argument, just like so:

`nmap -sU -p 1194 <ip.address>`